# How to add Disk Free Space performance counter to Azure Application Insights?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, performancecounter

I know that Azure Application Insights can collect additional performance counters using this syntax in ApplicationInsights.config:

```
  <Counters>
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Handle Count" ReportAs="Process handle count" />
    ...
  </Counters>

  PerformanceCounter must be either \CategoryName(InstanceName)\CounterName or \CategoryName\CounterName

  -->
</Add>
```

How do I actually add "Free Disk Space" and "Free Disk Space %" performance counters to this file?

Also, side note, I wish that Application Insights just already collected this, kind of surprising we have to go to these lengths to add it.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the settings below in ApplicationInsights.config:

```
 <Counters>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\LogicalDisk(_total)\% Free Space" ReportAs="the space perc"/>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\LogicalDisk(_total)\Free Megabytes" ReportAs="the space left"/>
 </Counters>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Ivan Yang's answer, it can also be done in code:

```
var perfCollectorModule = new PerformanceCollectorModule();
perfCollectorModule.Counters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(@"\Sales(photo)\# Items Sold", "Photo sales"));
perfCollectorModule.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);
```

[System performance counters in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/performance-counters)